# Definite integral involving Greatest Integer Function and arcsec(x) & arccot(x)

Tags: definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions, inverse-function, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{10\pi}(\lfloor arcsecx \rfloor+\lfloor arccotx \rfloor)dx$$

I have tried disintegrating the trigonometric functions into their acceptable principle domains, and then further disintegrate the integral into more parts opening up the greatest integer function, however I have failed miserably.

*One thing I clearly do not understand is, how can $arcsec(x)$ even exist under $(0,1)$*. Please shed some light.